# Find String in Text and Extract

Tags: c#, .net, string, search

Currently I am facing a problem. I have a list of Strings:

1. Pferde>Bandagen und Gamaschen>Glocken und Fesselschutz,Marken>Waldhausen,Pferde>Bandagen und Gamaschen
2. Pferde>Sattelzubehör>Zubehör,Marken>Waldhausen,Pferde>Sattelzubehör
3. Pferde>Sättel,Marken>Wintec
4. Marken>Wintec
5. Reiter>Reithelme und Sicherheit>Reflexartikel,Pferde>Bandagen und Gamaschen>Glocken und Fesselschutz,Marken>Waldhausen,Reiter>Reithelme und Sicherheit,Pferde>Bandagen und Gamaschen
6. Pferde>Trensen und Zubehör

I just want the value after `"Marken>"`. However, some lines have no `"Marken>"` and the place is not always the same.

Edit: Here is my code

```
// Hersteller Fix
string hersteller = "";
string input = tokens[22];


string pattern = @"((.*Marken\>)|(.*?))(?'target'.+)";

RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Singleline;

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
{
    hersteller = m.Index;
    hersteller = m.Groups["target"];
}
```

This is the output:

```
{Waldhausen,Pferde>Sattelzubehör}
```

But I need only "Waldhausen", "Wintec"...

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: My Code before:


string[] hname = tokens[22].Split(',');
string hersteller = "";

if (hname.Length == 1)
{
 string[] el = tokens[22].Split('>');
 hersteller = el[1];
}
if (hname.Length == 2)
{
 int index = hname.Length;
 hersteller = hname[index -1];
 string[] el = hersteller.Split('>');
 hersteller = el[1];
}
else if (hname.Length > 2)
{
 int index = hname.Length;
 hersteller = hname[index -2];
 string[] el = hersteller.Split('>');
 hersteller = el[1];
}

Comment: read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting

Comment: Grab the debugger, put a breakpoint at the beginning and step through your code. Inspect your variables to see what state your program is in and compare it to the state that it should be in at that point.

Comment: do you want to get value just after first "Marken>" ?

Comment: @Uttam Gupta - yes, only the first value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it without Regular Expressions, but really you should try yourself first before asking here on SO

```
var input = "Marken>Wintec";
string mark = "Marken>";

string output = null;

var start = input.IndexOf(mark);
if (start >= 0)
{
    var end = input.IndexOf(",", start);
    if (end >= 0)
    {
        output = input.Substring(start + mark.Length, end - start - mark.Length);   
    }
    else
    {
        output = input.Substring(start + mark.Length);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"((.*Marken\>)|(.*?))(?'target'.+)";
        string input = @"Pferde>Bandagen und Gamaschen>Glocken und Fesselschutz,Marken>Waldhausen,Pferde>Bandagen und Gamaschen
Pferde>Sattelzubehör>Zubehör,Marken>Waldhausen,Pferde>Sattelzubehör
Pferde>Sättel,Marken>Wintec
Marken>Wintec
Reiter>Reithelme und Sicherheit>Reflexartikel,Pferde>Bandagen und Gamaschen>Glocken und Fesselschutz,Marken>Waldhausen,Reiter>Reithelme und Sicherheit,Pferde>Bandagen und Gamaschen
Pferde>Trensen und Zubehör";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Groups["target"].Value.Trim(), m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @cRz The pattern itself is working, there was a minor issue with WriteLine. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var inputLine in inputList)
        {
            if (inputLine.Contains(target))
            {
                // Get everything in the line after the location of the target word
                // (indexOf(target) + target.Length ensures we start at the end of the target word, rather than the beginning
                var result = inputLine.Substring(inputLine.IndexOf(target) + target.Length);

                var indexOfSeparator = result.IndexOf('>');

                if (indexOfSeparator != -1)
                {
                    // Grab everything from the start of the string to the location of the separator
                    result = result.Substring(0, indexOfSeparator);
                }

                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try below logic if it works for you

```
 foreach (string x in lst)
            {
                int position = x.IndexOf("Marken>");
                string text = "";
                if (position > -1)
                {
                    text = x.Substring(position + 7);
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "Reiter>Reithelme und Sicherheit>Reflexartikel,Pferde>Bandagen und Gamaschen>Glocken und Fesselschutz,Marken>Waldhausen,Reiter>Reithelme und Sicherheit,Pferde>Bandagen und Gamaschen";

                List<String> Splitted = str.Split( ',' ).ToList();
                foreach ( String Split in Splitted )
                {
                    if ( Split.Contains("Marken"))
                    {
                        String value = Split.Split( '>' )[1];
                        Console.WriteLine( value );
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

result : Waldhausen